# Minecraft bot on Node.js

Tags: javascript, minecraft

I am trying to create a Minecraft bot to play on a skyblock server.
But the server I want to use has bot protection which checks if a player starts falling immediately after joining.
Bots start falling after a few seconds and protections just kicks my bot.

How I can make bot fall immediately like a real player?
I am using mineflare(https://github.com/PrismarineJS/mineflayer) to create a bot.

The code looks like this:

```
const bot = mineflayer.createBot({ // login to server
host: localhost,
port: 52566,
username: "MyBOT",
version: "1.15.2" 
})
```

Comment: Have you tried creating an issue on the Github of the stated bot? This is most likely an issue with their code.

Comment: Alternatively don't try to circumvent server rules

Answer (score -1):

```
const bot = mineflayer.createBot({ // login to server
  host: gazduirejocuri.ro,
  port: 25613,
  username: "MyBOT",
  version: "1.8.9" 
})
```

Comment: This does not explain what the problem was. It would be best to include some explanation instead of just providing an answer

Comment: Please provide an explanation which justifies the required changes.

Comment: You literally just modified the question.